# Proof Verification: Abelian groups have elements with orders equal to each of the group's prime divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, self-learning

I was self-studying out of Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0, and I came across this exercise:

> **Aluffi, Algrbra: Chapter 0, Exercise II.8.17**
>
> Assume $G$ is a finite abelian group, and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$.
>     Prove that there exists an element in $G$ of order $p$. (Hint: let $g$ be any element of $G$, and consider the subgroup $\langle g\rangle$; use the fact that this subgroup is cyclic to show that there is an element $h\in\langle g\rangle$ in $G$ of prime order $q$. If $q = p$ you are done; else, use the quotient $G/\langle h\rangle$ and induction.)

**My question:**

I feel fine with most of my proof (although it may be a bit drawn out), but I haven't quite convinced myself with the final paragraph, after the induction. I could say in the induction step, "If q=p, we're done. If not, move on to the next step," but this reminds of of the sort of '[algorithmic proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214454/algorithmic-proofs-in-linear-algebra)' seen in the earlier sections of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, which I feel are of questionable rigor. **Is there a better way to express the idea I'm going for in the final paragraph, is there a better idea altogether, or is my treatment just fine?**

**My proof:**

Let $G_0=G$. We will soon define each $G_k$ to be a quotient $G_{k-1}/H$, where $H$ is a subgroup of prime order. Let $\Omega(n)$ be the number of prime divisors of $n$, including multiplicity. We will proceed by (strong) induction on $k$, proving that, for $0\leq n < \Omega(|G|)$:

1. $\Omega(|G_n|) = \Omega(|G|) - n$
2. There exists an element of $|G_n|$ of prime order.
3. If $g\in G_n$ has prime order $p$, then there exists an element of $G$ of order p.

*Base Case (n=0):* Let $G_0=G$.

1. $\Omega(|G_0|) = \Omega(|G|) - 0$
2. Let $g_0\in G_0$, and for some prime divisor $q_0$ of |g_0|, let $h_0=g_0^{\frac{|g_0|}{q_0}}$. We then have $|h_0| = q_0$, so (2) holds.
3. Trivial.

*Induction (n=k+1):* Suppose (1), (2), and (3) hold for $n\leq k$. Let $H_k = \langle h_k\rangle$ (which is normal because $G$ is abelian), and define $G_{k+1}=G_k/H_k$.

1. We have: 
   $$
   \begin{align*}
             \Omega(|G_{k+1}|) &= \Omega\left(\left|\frac{G_k}{H}\right|\right) \\
             &= \Omega\left( \frac{|G_k|}{|H|} \right) \\
             &= \Omega\left( \frac{|G_k|}{q} \right) \\
             &= \Omega(|G_k|) - 1 \\
             &= \Omega(G) - k - 1
           \end{align*}
   $$
2. Same as the base case - let $q_{k+1}$ be a prime divisor of $|G_{k+1}|$, let $g_{k+1}\in G_{k+1}$, and define $h_{k+1}=g^{\frac{|g_{k+1}|}{q_{k+1}}}$. Then $|h_{k+1}|=q_{k+1}$.
3. Suppose $gH_k\in G_{k+1}$ has order $p$, where $p$ is a prime divisor of $|G_{k+1}|$. It then follows that $(gH_k)^p = e$, and so $g^p=h_k^m$ for some integer $m$. Since $e=(h^k)^x = g^{px}$ for some $x=|h^k|$, we then have $|g^x|=p$ in $G_k$. By our inductive hypothesis, then, we have an element of $G$ of order $p$, as desired.

The set $\{q_0, \dots, q_n\}$ where $n=\Omega(G)-1$ is the set of all prime divisors of $|G|$, since at each step of the process we have removed a prime divisor before choosing a new one. At the end of this process, we have proven that $G$ contains an element of order $q_n$ for each $n$, and hence an element of order $p$ for each prime divisor $p$ of $|G|$.

Comment: Hints: (1) try not to annoy people who have been trying to help you by deleting your MSE posts and then creating almost identical replacements. (2) do the proof by (what is known as course-of-values or complete) induction on the number of elements of $G$ and just follow the hint you have been given.

Comment: Dang, I knew my proof was convoluted! I was stuck in the "$n\implies n+1$" train of thought, and didn't realize how powerful strong induction is. Thanks for the tip!